# Extract links from html table

Tags: html, xml, r, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract the links from the following webpage http://ipt.humboldt.org.co/ that are of type "Specimen". I can get the table from the webpage using the following code:

```
library(XML)
sitePage<-htmlParse("http://ipt.humboldt.org.co/")
tableNodes<-getNodeSet(sitePage,"//table")
siteTable<-readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[1]])
```

However the links are missing after I use the readHTML command.

Answer (score 10):

It ended up being an intricate XPath expression:

```
library(XML)
sitePage<-htmlParse("http://ipt.humboldt.org.co/")
hyperlinksYouNeed<-getNodeSet(sitePage,"//table[@id='resourcestable']
                                        //td[5][.='Specimen']
                                        /preceding-sibling
                                        ::td[3]
                                        /a
                                        /@href")
```

but let me explain the XPath expression bit-by-bit:

- `//table[@id='resourcestable']` -> This way we are getting the main table on the page called 'resourcestable'
- `//td[5][.='Specimen']` -> Now we are filtering only these rows that have Type as *Specimen*
- `/preceding-sibling` -> Now we start looking backwards
- `::td[3]` -> 3 steps to be precise counting backwards from where we are. Be careful *preceding-sibling* start counting backwards therefore td[1] is the *Type* column, td[2] is the *Organisation* column and td[3] is the *Name* column we want.
- `/a` -> now get the included *a* node
- `/@href` -> and finally more precisely the href attribute content

Answer (score 5):

```
xmlFun<-function(x){
   y<-xpathSApply(x,'./a',xmlAttrs)
   if(length(y)>0){
      list(href=y,orig=xmlValue(x))
   }else{
      xmlValue(x)
   }
}
ans<-readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[1]],elFun=xmlFun,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ans$Name<-lapply(ans$Name,function(x){unlist(eval(parse(text=x)))})
ans$Name[ans$Subtype=='Specimen']
```