# Extracting html links from table over multiple columns

Tags: xml, r

I am having trouble reading a HTML table into R that keeps the hyperlinks inside the cells of the tables. I found this solution ([Extract links from html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290402/extract-links-from-html-table-using-r)) but I believe the function provided in the second answer only works when the HTML table has links in a single column, and I am unable to find a solution to make it work for a table with links in multiple columns.

For example, I want to extract the table from;

http://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/countries/NED/

but instead of just using the basic `readHTMLTable` function from the XML, I want to know how to construct a function to put into the `elFun` section so that the first row might look contain instead of "2014 Winter" will contain "/olympics/countries/NED/winter/2014/".

Furthermore, I would like to keep multiple links per cell when present, as in the third row for Top Medalists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this as a starting point:

```
library(XML)
getHrefs <- function(node, encoding) 
  if (!is.null(xmlChildren(node)$a)) { 
    paste(xpathSApply(node, './a', xmlGetAttr, "href"), collapse = ",")
  } else {
    return(xmlValue(xmlChildren(node)$text))
  }
head( readHTMLTable("http://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/countries/NED/", which = 1, elFun = getHrefs)  )
# Rk                                Games                                          Flag Bearer Participants Men Women Sports Gold Silver Bronze Total                                                                    Top Medalist(s)
# 1  1 /olympics/countries/NED/winter/2014/         /olympics/athletes/te/jorien-ter-mors-1.html           39  20    19      4    8      7      9    24                                            /olympics/athletes/wu/ireen-wust-1.html
# 2  2 /olympics/countries/NED/summer/2012/ /olympics/athletes/va/dorian-van-rijsselberge-1.html          173  94    79     19    6      6      8    20                                   /olympics/athletes/kr/ranomi-kromowidjojo-1.html
# 3  3 /olympics/countries/NED/winter/2010/            /olympics/athletes/be/timothy-beck-1.html           32  15    17      4    4      1      3     8 /olympics/athletes/kr/sven-kramer-1.html,/olympics/athletes/tu/mark-tuitert-1.html
# 4  4 /olympics/countries/NED/summer/2008/           /olympics/athletes/de/jeroen-delmee-1.html          237 139    98     20    7      5      4    16                                     /olympics/athletes/va/anky-van-grunsven-1.html
# 5  5 /olympics/countries/NED/winter/2006/                 /olympics/athletes/bo/jan-bos-1.html           33  16    17      4    3      2      4     9                                                           4 athletes with 2 medals
# 6  6 /olympics/countries/NED/summer/2004/           /olympics/athletes/hu/mark-huizinga-1.html          210 134    76     22    4      9      9    22                                        /olympics/athletes/de/inge-de-bruijn-1.html
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Could you explain the encoding input? I looked for a help file for this but was unsuccessful.

Comment: @jimmako Good question, I also didn't find any information on it. I just tried it out due to the error message `Error in (function (node)  : unused argument (encoding = 0)`, which I received with just one function parameter...